# Is there a way to have pagination show up at the bottom of a table?

Tags: pagination

Entry pagination is a pretty simple thing except with tables. Whenever I do pagination on table data it only displays at the top. Is there a way to get it to show up at the bottom?

Here is the code I am using.

```
<table id="vip">
<thead>
<tr>

<th scope="col">State</th>
<th scope="col">CC</th>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
<th scope="col">Posiition</th>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Phone</th>
<th scope="col">email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{exp:user:users orderby="stake" sort="asc" group_id="9|12" limit="50" paginate="top"}
<tr>

<td><strong>{state}</strong></td>
<td>{council}</td>
<td>{screen_name}</td>
<td>{occupation}</td>
<td>{location}</td>
<td>{phone}</td>
<td><a href="mailto:{email}">{email}</a></td>
</tr>
{paginate}
<p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} page(s)  {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:user:users}
</tbody>

</table>
```

If I do paginate="both", I get two pagination links at the top. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using table tags in your pagination code:

```
{paginate}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} page(s)  {pagination_links}</p></td>
    </tr>
{/paginate}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
{exp:user:users orderby="stake" sort="asc" group_id="9|12" limit="50" paginate="bottom"}
{if count == 1}
<table id="vip">
<thead>
<tr>

<th scope="col">State</th>
<th scope="col">CC</th>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
<th scope="col">Posiition</th>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Phone</th>
<th scope="col">email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{/if}

<tr>

<td><strong>{state}</strong></td>
<td>{council}</td>
<td>{screen_name}</td>
<td>{occupation}</td>
<td>{location}</td>
<td>{phone}</td>
<td><a href="mailto:{email}">{email}</a></td>
</tr>

{if count == total_results}
</tbody>

</table>
{/if}

{paginate}
<p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} page(s)  {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:user:users}
```